# iOS swift remove elements of an array from another array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have two arrays

```
var array1 = new Array ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
var array2 = new Array ["a", "c", "d"]
```

I want to remove elements of array2 from array1

```
Result ["b", "e"]
```

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The easiest way is to convert both arrays to sets, subtract the second from the first, convert to the result to an array and assign it back to `array1`:

```
array1 = Array(Set(array1).subtracting(array2))
```

Note that your code is not valid Swift - you can use type inference to declare and initialize both arrays as follows:

```
var array1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
var array2 = ["a", "c", "d"]
```

Comment: Can you subtract an array from a set? Wouldn't that need to be `array1 = Array(Set(array1).subtract(Set(array2)))` (Converting Array2 to a set before subtracting it from array1?)

Comment: @DuncanC: the `subtract` method (as well as many other `Set` methods) takes a `SequenceType` argument, so yes, you can pass an array.

Comment: I use:
`/* Swift 3.x */ func - <Element: Hashable>(lhs: [Element], rhs: [Element]) -> [Element] {
 return Array(Set<Element>(lhs).subtracting(Set<Element>(rhs)))
}`

Comment: That's really nice - it also seems to respect the original order - is that always guaranteed?

Comment: The order is not guaranteed:

> An unordered collection of unique elements.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set

Comment: Only useful if your elements are `Hashable`, while for this kind of thing you only need `Equatable`.

Answer (score 133):

@[Antonio's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31984505/5501940) is more performant, but this preserves ordering, if that's important:

```
var array1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
let array2 = ["a", "c", "d"]
array1 = array1.filter { !array2.contains($0) }
```

Comment: loving this method

Comment: good answer! but do you know how to write this on obj-c ? please help me out :) thanks

Comment: If the elements are `Hashable` like they are in this case, it might be more performant to convert `array2` into a `Set` first; this would still preserve the order as `array1` remains an array, but you can perform fast lookups on the search collection.

Comment: To make it work, your object also has to conform to the Equatable protocol. If it doesn't you get this weird error in Swift 4.0 saying: Missing argument label 'where:' in call in the contains function inside the filter.

Comment: @c1pherB1t yes, you can add the `where:`in the `contains`
i.e.
```array1 = array1.filter({ item in !array2.contains(where: { $0.id == item.id }) })```

Comment: The complexity of the solution is O(n²) ? I am looking for an optimised solution.

Comment: u are comparing 2 arrays. it will always be O(n^2)

Answer (score 9):

**Remove elements using indexes array:**

1. Array of Strings and indexes

   ```
   let animals = ["cats", "dogs", "chimps", "moose", "squarrel", "cow"]
   let indexAnimals = [0, 3, 4]
   let arrayRemainingAnimals = animals
       .enumerated()
       .filter { !indexAnimals.contains($0.offset) }
       .map { $0.element }

   print(arrayRemainingAnimals)

   //result - ["dogs", "chimps", "cow"]
   ```
2. Array of Integers and indexes

   ```
   var numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
   let indexesToRemove = [3, 5, 8, 12]

   numbers = numbers
       .enumerated()
       .filter { !indexesToRemove.contains($0.offset) }
       .map { $0.element }

   print(numbers)

   //result - [0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11]
   ```

**Remove elements using element value of another array**

3. Arrays of integers

   ```
   let arrayResult = numbers.filter { element in
       return !indexesToRemove.contains(element)
   }
   print(arrayResult)

   //result - [0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11]
   ```
4. Arrays of strings

   ```
   let arrayLetters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]
   let arrayRemoveLetters = ["a", "e", "g", "h"]
   let arrayRemainingLetters = arrayLetters.filter {
       !arrayRemoveLetters.contains($0)
   }

   print(arrayRemainingLetters)

   //result - ["b", "c", "d", "f", "i"]
   ```

Answer (score 4):

You can create sets and then use the subtract method

```
let setA = Set(arr1)
let setB = Set(arr2)
setA.subtract(setB)
```

Comment: intersect show the elements in common , i want to delete the elements in common and get the others in another array

Comment: I update the code, for that you need to use subtract

Answer (score 4):

Here is an extension with @jrc answer:

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    func subtracting(_ array: Array<Element>) -> Array<Element> {
        self.filter { !array.contains($0) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice approach but if you have a million entries this is n^2

Answer (score 3):

out of scope but it would help me if it had been here. 
removing subArray from array in **OBJECTIVE-C**

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"not (self IN %@)", subArrayToBeDeleted];
NSArray* finalArray = [initialArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

hope it will ever help someone :)

Comment: That’s not very efficient. Just do this: `[[array1 mutableCopy] removeObjectsInArray:array2]`

Answer (score 1):

An extended version of the answer by Shai Balassiano:

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
  func subtracting(_ array: [Element]) -> [Element] {
      self.filter { !array.contains($0) }
  }

  mutating func remove(_ array: [Element]) {
      self = self.subtracting(array)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more solution by defining your own PredicateSet.

```
struct PredicateSet<A> {
  let contains: (A) -> Bool
}

let animals = ["Cow", "Bulldog", "Labrador"]
let dogs = ["Bulldog", "Labrador"]

let notDogs = PredicateSet { !dogs.contains($0) }

print(animals.filter(notDogs.contains)) // ["Cow"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are 2 arrays which contains duplicated element, and you need just a simple subtraction, You can use this code. This works for `String` type as well.

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    func subtracting(_ array: Array<Element>) -> Array<Element> {
        var result: Array<Element> = []
        var toSub = array
        
        for i in self {
            if let index = toSub.firstIndex(of: i) {
                toSub.remove(at: index)
                continue
            }
            else {
                result.append(i)
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}


let first = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 7]
let second = [2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6]
let result = first.subtracting(second)

//print result 
//[1, 1, 3, 7, 7]
```