# How to check if 2 arrays have the same element and if it does, delete that element from one of the arrays?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I currently have 2 arrays, one called rewardsArray and one called expiredRewardsArray.  The rewardsArray I'm getting from an api thats fetched every time I connect. The expiredRewardsArray I save locally.  What I'm trying to do is in the viewDidLoad, after I retrieve the rewardsArray data I want to compare it to the expiredRewardsArray's data.  If there is a match I want to remove the item from the rewardsArray.  This is what I have so far but it never goes inside the "if let" brackets so it's not removing the item from the rewardsArray:

```
 func rewardsMinusExpired () {

    expiredRewardsArray = rewardManager.getExpiredRewards()

    for expiredReward in expiredRewardsArray {
      if let ex = rewardsArray.indexOf(expiredReward){

        print("Expired Reward to be removed: \(ex)")

        rewardsArray.removeAtIndex(ex)

        rewardsTableView.reloadData()
      }
    }
  }
```

Each item in the array has an id, I use that to see if the item is in the expiredRewardsArray:

```
 for expiredReward in expiredRewardsArray {
       print("This is an expired reward: \(expiredReward.id)")
    }
```

Comment: is the ordering of elements important?

Comment: in the rewards array it is, not in the expired rewards array

Comment: Oh, I just posted a solution for where ordering doesn't matter =/

Comment: Could you clarify in what way this doesn't work? Your code is fine - are you sure `rewardManager` is retrieving the expired awards properly?

Comment: Have a look at [iOS swift remove elements of an array from another array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31984435/ios-swift-remove-elements-of-an-array-from-another-array).

Comment: Oh - based on your edit, I think I might understand the problem better. What is the type of `expiredRewardsArray`? If `expiredRewardsArray` contains objects, since objects are reference types, the members of `expiredRewardsArray` will never appear in `rewardsArray`. If that's the case, you won't be able to use `indexOf(_:)`, you'll have to compare them using their `id` property.

Comment: I just posted an answer explaining this that gets around the problem of reference types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `expiredRewardsArray` and `rewardsArray` are arrays of objects, then you'll need to compare the elements using their `id` property to compare them, rather than `indexOf(_:)`. The reason for this is that objects are reference types, so you can have two different objects with identical properties, but if they're not the same object, `indexOf(_:)` will treat them as separate entities.

Try this code instead:

```
func rewardsMinusExpired() {
    expiredRewardsArray = rewardManager.getExpiredRewards()

    rewardsArray = rewardsArray.filter { reward in
        let isExpired = expiredRewardsArray.contains { expiredReward in
            return expiredReward.id == reward.id
        }
        return !isExpired
    }
}
```

Comment: When I try this it jumps over the filter part

Comment: That is... extremely strange. Can you provide any more information about the context of the problem?

Comment: I have the custom class as type class- MemberRewardsInfo: NSObject, Mappable, NSCoding, could this be affecting it?

Comment: This worked best in my situation because it was a custom object

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that uses Set arithmetic. As a consequence, it's really fast, but it will not preserve the ordering of elements, and it will clobber any duplicates. It runs in linear time (`O(n)`), whereas a naive approach would be `O(n^2)`.

```
let unexpiredRewards = Set(rewardsArray).subtract(Set(ExpiredRewards))
```

Comment: This doesn't work, possibly because the id is used to identify the rewards?

Comment: `Set` uses the [`Equatable`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Equatable_Protocol/index.html) to determine object equality. You'll want to conform to that protocol, and implement `==` such that 2 `Reward` instances are equal if `$0.id == $1.id`

Answer (score 2):

```
for item in expiredRewardsArray {
    if let index = rewardsArray.index(of: item) { 
        //found the item
        rewardsArray.remove(at: index)
    }
}
```

This will find the item and delete it from the rewardsArray

UPDATE:

You say that each item has an id. If with the code above the if let block is never called than you can be sure that the items aren't actually the same or you don't have any equal items.

```
for itemOne in expiredRewardsArray {
    for itemTwo in rewardsArray { 
        if itemOne.id == itemTwo.id {
            rewardsArray.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
}
```

Not very performant but it does its job and keeps the order

Comment: Just tried this, it doesn't go inside the " if let index" brackets

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

You should really use swift method filter in cases like this. This can be easily solved as this,

```
func rewardMinusExpired() {
    let notExpiredRewards = rewardsArray.filter { a in
        return !expiredRewardArray.contains(a)
    }
}
```